# String.format() vs decimalformat - thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, formatting, thread-safety

I am looking to round the number to 2 decimal points in my code and tried to use decimalformat but I learnt online that it is not thread safe to use. I tried String.format() which also works for my case but I could not find any documents if it is thread safe or not? Is String.format() can be used safely in multi-threaded application or will it have same problem as decimalformat

Comment: DECIMAL_FORMAT.get().format(score)

Comment: String.format("%.2f", ("score"))

Answer (score 4):

Non-thread-safe classes are only a problem when *shared* between two or more threads. As long as each thread has its own instance, there are no thread-safety issues.

Compare the following two code snippets (assuming some form of thread-based web server dispatching to controller methods).

The first one uses a shared instance of `DecimalFormat` and as such is not thread-safe. Different threads will use the same instance and your program will generate bogus data.

```
class Controller {
  private DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();

  public String endpoint(int input) {
    format.format(input);
  }
}
```

The second one creates a new instance for every thread and is therefore safe.

```
class Controller {
  public String endpoint(int input) {
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
    format.format(input);
  }
}
```

`String#format` is always thread-safe.